# JSF - ajax call in composite fires only once

Tags: jsf, web, binding

i have a simple jsf composite component to which i pass a bean.
I want to fire a bean method when clicking a button in the composite.
This should be done via AJAX

Composite definition (also uses a method binding just for testing):

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="deviceMain" type="com.db.nwd.webappls.app.model.device.InvDeviceMain" />
    <composite:attribute name="saveAction" method-signature="void save(com.db.nwd.webappls.app.model.device.InvDeviceMain)" />
    <composite:attribute name="bean" type="com.db.nwd.webappls.app.managedbeans.ShowDeviceBean" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:form id="myForm">
            ...
            <h:commandButton action="#{cc.attrs.saveAction}" value="default" >
                <f:ajax render="myForm" execute="myForm"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <b:commandButton ajax="true" value="Save with bean" look="primary" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.bean.save(cc.attrs.deviceMain)}" />
        </b:panel>
    </h:form>
</composite:implementation>
```

Using the composite and binding looks like this

```
<netappls:deviceSimpleEdit deviceMain="#{showDeviceBean.deviceMain}" saveAction="#{showDeviceBean.save(showDeviceBean.deviceMain)}" bean="#{showDeviceBean}" />
```

As you can see i tried both ways of how to execute an action inside the composite (passing bean and passing function)

Implementation:

```
public void save(InvDeviceMain device) {
        System.out.println("Save " + device.getDeviceMainUid());
    }
```

I also have tried to use the action attribute of the button and not the action-listener.

In each case the button only fires once. After that nothing happens.

Comment: Are there any Javascript errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No Javascript errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

The page where the composite is used is called with a uri get parameter.

```
<f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam id="deviceId" name="deviceId" value="#{showDeviceBean.deviceUid}"/>
            <f:viewAction action="#{showDeviceBean.onInit}" />
        </f:metadata>
```

This parameter was before defined as required="true". In this case the described issue happens.
When i remove the required flag the ajax call works.

Can somehow explain me this please?